# Jupyter online compiler integration to the website

Tags: python, api, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to build a coding platform where we need to use Jupyter Notebook as the online compiler.

Can anybody share the process to access the API for the Jupyter Notebook?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question, possibly better answered on official Jupyter Discourse. It just happens that there is already a discussion on this topic here: [Integrate jupyterlab with my webapp](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/integrate-jupyterlab-with-my-webapp/9118/1).

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Tweeter and YouTube Apis and you can see my code on my Github here: https://github.com/Ulewsky/Analysis_of_unstructured_data it should be in 3rd and 4th list. However, you can also find information on how to build a specific API on the website of each Apis provider. If you will have some specific questions about the code don't hesitate to ask.